# CircleCI Java 11 build fail

Tags: maven, spring-boot, java-11, circleci-2.0

I have a small spring boot rest api. It was built in java 8, recently I switched to java 11 and have the following problem. It builds localy and works fine, but it can not build on circleci.com. It can not find tools.jar, because it isn't part of jdk since version 9. How can I find the dependency that triggers this?
I'm using intellij 2018.3. I tried looking at maven dependency tree, but there is no search option.
Once again, it works localy.

CircleCI error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
mvn dependency:go-offline
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.smort:rest-demo >-------------------------
[INFO] Building rest-demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:go-offline (default-cli) > :resolve-plugins @ rest-demo >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:resolve-plugins (resolve-plugins) @ rest-demo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.651 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-27T18:00:19Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:resolve-plugins (resolve-plugins) on project rest-demo: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Exited with code 1
```

config.yml:

```
# Java Maven CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:11

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: mvn dependency:go-offline

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

      # run tests! and gen code coverage
      - run: mvn integration-test cobertura:cobertura

      - store_test_results:
          path: target/surefire-reports

      - run:
          name: Send to CodeCov
          command: bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.smort</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>rest-demo</name>
    <description>Spring 5 REST Demo</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <springfox-swagger2.version>2.9.2</springfox-swagger2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--swagger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--end of swagger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--security test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--end of security test-->
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                    <check/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with cobertura plug in. It does not support java 11.